# Reject database table items using condition in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my database

| studentId | course | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CSE115 | F |
| 2 | CSE115 | C |
| 3 | CSE115 | A |
| 3 | EEE111 | B |
| 2 | EEE111 | F |
| 1 | EEE111 | B |

I want to execute a query that will only return the 'studentId' who has not failed in any course(No 'F' with the studentId in the table). In my example table I have showed only two courses(CSE115,EEE111) but in my case it can be 30 courses and only those student will be selected who has passed in all the courses given to the table. If a student passed in 29 courses except 1 course he will not be selected.

For example in the given table the output will be,
**Output:**

| studentId | course | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | CSE115 | A |
| 3 | EEE111 | B |

**Can anyone help me building the query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the `studentId`s that failed at least once with this query:

```
SELECT studentId FROM tablename WHERE grade = 'F'
```

Use it with `NOT IN` to get the rows that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE studentId NOT IN (SELECT studentId FROM tablename WHERE grade = 'F')
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename tt WHERE tt.studentId = t.studentId AND grade = 'F')
```